# <iframe> is not using available space in css grid (Chrome, Edge, Opera) but it works on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have a website that displays some youtube videos in a popup window.
I tested everything using Firefox while writing the code. And it behaves the way I want to in Firefox: Half of the popup is the video, the other half is made out of divs. [Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw8PT.jpg)

But if I open the page using Chrome, Opera or Edge it behaves like this: The popup is divided correctly but the YouTube iframe has only minimum height
[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHku.jpg).

**I tried to fix it** using `height: 100%` on the iframe. It changed nothing in Firefox but on the other browsers it made the iframe grid area bigger than I want it to be

Does anyone know how I can make it look like in Firefox on the other browsers?

The popup window code looks like this:

```
         <div class="popup">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

            <div id="tpop">
               //...
            </div>

            <div id="ipop">
               //...
            </div>'

            <div id="kpop">
               //...
            </div>

            <div id="bpop">
                //...
            </div>

         </div>
```

and my css is:

```
.popup {
    background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    bottom:40px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50fr 50fr;
    grid-template-rows: 60fr 24px 40fr;
    grid-template-areas: "iframe iframe"
                        "tpop ipop"
                        "kpop bpop";
}

iframe {
    grid-area: iframe;
    width: 100%;
}

#kpop {
    grid-area: kpop;
}

#bpop {
    grid-area: bpop;
}

#ipop {
    grid-area: ipop;
}


#tpop {
    grid-area: tpop;
}
```

Comment: If you give an upvote and you remember to set the accepted answer i tell you how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set **height : 60 vh** in **iframe** class.

```html
iframe {
    grid-area: iframe;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;


}
```

Below is the tested output in various browsers.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why this fixes the problem? Why 60vh? Why not some other value?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the !important tag on a parent element in the selector to override the iframe's properties.

Take a look:

```
body iframe {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```